# how to repeat header ROWS for each group within the same page in ssrs 2012

Tags: ssrs-2012

how to repeat header ROWS for each group within the same page in ssrs 2012[how to repeat header ROWS for each group within the same page in ssrs 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzAd8.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag & drop List from Toolbox (or right-click on report body Insert - > List) on to the report body 
   and then drag & drop Table from Toolbox inside the List as shown below:
   [image]
2. Then assign Dataset columns to the report Table columns:
   [image]
3. After assigning columns, if we preview the report we will end up with the error shown below:
   [image]
4. Again go to the Design Pane, click on the List - > at the bottom, go to Row Groups - > =(Details) ->
   in the drop down list click on Group Properties ... 
   Under Group Properties, follow the settings as shown in images below:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Expected report is to repeat the rows header within 1 table as per image.

Comment: Well you do get Repeat Rows within Table for a group.
You have to go step by step to achieve your final Report. Your current problem of grouping and then keeping Row header is solved, Just keep the table Intact.

Comment: Thanks For quick reply , How to achieve below problems                                                                                    
 1. Few Columns from child are shown on  column header and few are shown on row header. 

2. Row header needs to repeat as per below image ( childrow5,6,7)

Comment: Did you added screenshot, Could you please add screenshot of current Result from Report